# Make sure that dynamic_cast won't cause undefined behaviour C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, undefined-behavior, dynamic-cast

Up to this day I thought that if I have class `A` and `B` that are not related in any way, the `dynamic_cast` using pointers would fail returning `nullptr`. Now I've read that this causes undefined behaviour...

[cppreference - dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast#Explanation):

> When `dynamic_cast` is used in a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly), and expression refers to the object that's currently under construction/destruction, the object is considered to be the most derived object. If `new_type` is not a pointer or reference to the constructor's/destructor's own class or one of its bases, the behavior is undefined.

I have code like this:

```
class ActorComponent
{
    ActorComponent* m_parent;
public:
    template <typename _type>
    _type* getParent() const {
        return dynamic_cast<_type*>(m_parent);
    }

    ActorComponent(ActorComponent* parent) {
        // using `getParent` inside the constructor:
        auto p = this->getParent<int>(); // `int` obviously isn't base of the ActorComponent
    }
};
```

I need to limit `_type` to type that is either

- equal to `ActorComponent`
- derived from `ActorComponent`

... and possibly more.

The question is: how to make sure in compile-time that `dynamic_cast` to such `_type` won't cause undefined behaviour? Will simple

```
template <typename _type,
    typename = std::enable_if_t< std::is_base_of_v<ActorComponent, std::remove_cv_t<_type> > || std::is_same_v<ActorComponent, std::remove_cv_t<_type> > >
```

always work?

Comment: are you sure you have read/pasted the whole statement as is? I think you are missing some sentences in the sixth clause where you obtained the verbatim?

Comment: *"When `dynamic_cast` is used in a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly), and __expression__ refers to the object that's currently under construction/destruction, the object is considered to be the most derived object. If __new_type__ is not a pointer or reference to the constructor's/destructor's own class or one of its bases, the behavior is undefined."* - you don't seem to be doing this in your example

Comment: That clause only applies within a constructor or destructor.

Comment: You are right. However, the same situation happens when I use `getParent` in the constructor.

Comment: Why don't you show the code you're actually concerned about, where you think case 6 is applicable? What's the point of _only_ showing the code where your quote _doesn't_ apply?

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: Calling a constructor/destructor with `nullptr` or `std::bad_cast`, as in the case of illegal `dynamic_cast`ing of pointers or references, respectively, is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You are still not `dynamic_cast`ing the object that is being constructed - you are casting a member of your object

Comment: You are right. Well this whole question turned out to be an act of misunderstanding the documentation. Sorry for that!

Comment: and `p` in the modified version of your code is well-defined: `nullptr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** It's fine. For some reason you picked up on a condition that clearly doesn't apply to your code.

---

Your quote:

> If new_type is not a pointer or reference to the constructor's/destructor's own class or one of its bases, the behavior is undefined.

is obviously about using `dynamic_cast` inside a constructor or destructor, although for some reason you omitted the complete context:

> Only the following conversions can be done with dynamic_cast, ...
>
> 1) ... 5) ...
>
> 6) When dynamic_cast is used in a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly), and expression refers to the object that's currently under construction/destruction, the object is considered to be the most derived object. If new_type is not a pointer or reference to the constructor's/destructor's own class or one of its bases, the behavior is undefined.

Since you're not using it inside a constructor or destructor, case 6 is obviously irrelevant.

The case actually relevant to your code is:

> 5) If expression is a pointer or reference to a polymorphic type Base, and new_type is a pointer or reference to the type Derived a run-time check is performed:
>
> > a) The most derived object pointed/identified by expression is examined. If, in that object, expression points/refers to a public base of Derived, and if only one subobject of Derived type is derived from the subobject pointed/identified by expression, then the result of the cast points/refers to that Derived subobject. (This is known as a "downcast".)
> >
> > b) Otherwise, if expression points/refers to a public base of the most derived object, and, simultaneously, the most derived object has an unambiguous public base class of type Derived, the result of the cast points/refers to that Derived (This is known as a "sidecast".)
> >     c) Otherwise, the runtime check fails. If the dynamic_cast is used on pointers, the null pointer value of type new_type is returned. If it was used on references, the exception std::bad_cast is thrown.

---

Examining the code edited in later:

```
ActorComponent(ActorComponent* parent) {
    // using `getParent` inside the constructor:
    // `int` obviously isn't base of the ActorComponent
    auto p = this->getParent<int>();
}
```

the first part of clause 6's condition

> When dynamic_cast is used in a constructor or a destructor (directly or indirectly) ...

*is* met (the `getParent` code is indirectly in a constructor), but the second part:

> ... and expression refers to the object that's currently under construction/destruction ...

is *not* satisfied, so clause 6 still doesn't apply.

You're casting `m_parent`, which is a member subobject of the `ActorComponent` object you're constructing. Since member subobjects are completely constructed by the time you enter the body of your constructor, *that* object is *not* being constructed and we are not in *that object's* constructor. Apart from anything else, *that object* (`m_parent`) is a pointer, which doesn't have a constructor. As an aside, it's uninitialized, so your code is anyway completely illegal, but not for the reason you asked about.

Comment: That was mentioned comments, and subsequently edited into the question, _after_ I wrote this answer. I'll update to address the change when I have time.